# Is Realm.Configuration() synchronous or asynchronous when doing migration?

Tags: swift, realm

In this tutorial https://ali-akhtar.medium.com/migration-with-realm-realmswift-part-6-11c3a7b24955

Is the following code:

[image]

All this code is synchronous - the try! Realm(configuration: configuration) assumes tht the configuration has completed and is valid.

But what if there are hundreds of thousands or millions of objects to migrate, and the migration steps are complex, such that iterating through them will take some time, then what happens?

Will the thread hang until the Realm.Configuration() has completed and then the next line will execute sucesfully. Or is Realm.Configuration() implementation asynchronous and so the try! will crash because Realm.Configuration() is doing a lengthy task in another thread?

Comment: It’s a good idea to include code, errors and and structures as *text*, not links and images. That way, if they are needed in an answer, they can be copied and pasted. See [images and links are evil](http://idownvotedbecau.se/imageofcode). Also, images are not searchable which may prevent future readers from locating the question. Take a look at [No Images Please](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/285551/why-not-upload-images-of-code-errors-when-asking-a-question)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Super interesting question and the answer is contained in the documentation but let me provide some details.

Also, for clarity, a migration only applies to local-only Realms. If you are using Realm Sync (MongoDB Realm) migrations do not apply.

The code in the tutorial, and the code in the question assumes the migration is not going to be time consuming. However, that may not always be the case - there could be millions of objects processed in the migration

Therefore using Realm.asyncOpen will asynchronously open a Realm and allow a migration to be performed on a background thread.

[asyncOpen(configuration:)](https://docs.mongodb.com/realm-sdks/swift/latest/Structs/Realm.html#/s:10RealmSwift0A0V9asyncOpen13configurationAA0A10PublishersO05AsyncD9PublisherVAC13ConfigurationV_tFZ)

Keep in mind the migration doesn't occur until Realm is actually opened.

So at a high level an async function could be set up to define the migration function, open Realm with .async which will start the migration and then a completion handler is called when done. Something like

```
MyMigrationHandler
   static func doMigrate(completion: @escaping() -> Void {
      let someConfig = Realm.Configuration(... define migration closure

      Realm.asyncOpen(configuration: someConfig ) { result in
         Realm.Configuration.configuration = someConfig
         handle result being .failure or .success
         completion()
      }
   }
}
```

and it would be called asynchronously

```
MyMigrationHandler.doMigrate {
   this code executes once the migration has completed
}
```